# Is it possible to make all <a> tags open in a new window/tab?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm making a webpage with a lot of links, which should all open in a new tab using `target="_blank"`.

Is it possible to apply this to all `<a>` tags by default, so I can spare the time by not inserting it a every link?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes - you can specify a base target in the page's head:

```
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_base_target.asp).

If you need to override this for a particular link so that it *doesn't* open in a new window, you can do this manually by setting that link's `target` to `"_self"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: No problem. W3 has lots of good stuff around this sort of thing, always worth a quick search there first.

Comment: Getting curious here. Can you tell me if it actually is possible to apply an attribute to all tags of any type? Not only target for <a>.

Comment: I believe just base target and href - hence I edited the title of the question. I think for anything else, you'd have to use JS/JQuery, though I could be wrong. More here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp